# how to pass a python variable into a bash script function

Tags: python, bash, automation, scripting

I have searched and searched and searched but have not found and answer to my particular situation, or if I had I don't know how to implement it.  I'm trying to create a script using python and bash to automate my project creation process.  Whereas I would run the testing.py "as it is called now because I'm testing" with 1 command line argument which would be the name of the project folder, then it would ask "where I would like to create the project" with two options for paths to store the project and store the path using an if statement into the path variable.  then I would like to pass that variable in the bash script to navigate to it and create the project directory there.  here is what I have so far:

so the command that I would run is like:

`python testing.py newProject`

in the .test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function testing() {
    cd 
    desktop
    python testing.py $1

}
```

and in the testing.py

```
import sys
import os

school = "/Users/albert/Open/Microverse/"
personal = "/Users/albert/Open/code/Projects/"

path = " "

userInput = input("What type of project would you like to create? Personal or School? ")

if userInput.lower() == "personal":
    path = personal
elif userInput.lower() == "school":
    path = school


def testing():
    folderName = str(sys.argv[1])
    os.makedirs(path + str(folderName))
    print(folderName)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testing()
```

Comment: What is failing here?

Comment: when I run the python script it will only create the project folder on the desktop because that is where I have both the .test.sh and testing.py files stored but I don't know-how to pass the path variable from python which has the correct path to the bash script function.

Comment: I know that the path variable is getting the correct path because when I run it in the terminal with just the print(path) in the function and print the path variable it outputs the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Use "$1" instead of $1 as shown below

```
python testing.py "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your bash function like this

```
testing $1
```

The whole script

```
#!/bin/bash

function testing() {
    cd
    desktop
    python test.py $1
}

testing $1
```

And change `input()` to `raw_input()` in your python part. Input() function returns will actually evaluate the input string and try to run it as Python code. And if i try to input `Personal` this give me an error

```
What type of project would you like to create? Personal or School? Personal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    userInput = input("What type of project would you like to create? Personal or School? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Personal' is not defined
```

And if you input `personal` than `userInput` will be `/Users/albert/Open/code/Projects/` wich is not wat you want right?

Comment: You are assuming here that `python` is Python 2, but it's quite possible that the OP is actually using Python 3 and that `input()` is entirely correct (albeit inconvenient; see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `desktop` is not actually a valid command, and that you really want

```sh
testing () {
    cd ~/Desktop
    python test.py "$1"
]
```

A better design might be to not force all projects to be created inside your desktop folder, though.

```sh
testing () {
   python ~/Desktop/test.py "$1"
}
```

will let you run the script in any directory.

A still better design would be to give the script a proper shebang, mark it executable, call it `testing`, and save it in your `PATH`; then you don't need a shell function at all.

A different and IMHO more usable approach would be to allow the user to specify "personal" or "school" as part of the command line, instead of forcing the script to use interactive input. Requiring interactive I/O makes the script harder to use as a building block in further automation, and robs the user of the ability to use the shell's history and completion features.

The following refactoring hard-codes a very crude option parser, and uses a `dict` to map the project type to a specific folder name.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os

paths = {
  "school": "/Users/albert/Open/Microverse/"
  "personal": "/Users/albert/Open/code/Projects/"
}

def makeproject(type, folder):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, folder))

def gettype():
    while True:
        userInput = input("What type of project would you like to create? Personal or School? ")
        if userInput in paths:
            return paths[userInput]
        print("Not a valid option: {} -- try again".format(userInput))

def testing():
    idx = 1
    if sys.argv[idx] == "--school":
        type = paths["school"]
        idx = 1
    elif sys.argv[idx] == "--personal":
        type = paths["personal"
        idx = 2
    else:
        type = gettype()
    folderName = sys.argv[idx]
    makeproject(type, folderName)
    print(folderName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testing()
```

Notice that `sys.argv` and the value returned by `input` are already strings; there is no need to call `str()` on them.